# Is it possible to get Rails associations to return subclasses instead of the superclass?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations, metaprogramming

First, the inheritance approach may not be correct. If so, please explain a different approach.

Here is an example of the setup.

I have many applications, other than using the exact same database, that are not connected. To dry up the code base, I have an engine with all of the active record classes. I would like to keep application specific scopes and methods within the main applications.

In my Rails engine,

```
class MyEngine::User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dogs
end

class MyEngine::Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

In my main app,

```
class User < MyEngine::User
end

class Dog < MyEngine::Dog
  # EDITED TO SHOW EXAMPLE OF HOW SCOPE DOESN'T BELONG IN ENGINE
  DOGS_WITH_SPOTS_IDS = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]

  scope :with_spots, -> { where(id: DOGS_WITH_SPOTS_IDS) }
end
```

The issue in my main app,

```
user = User.last
user.dogs
# => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy[#<MyEngine::Dog spots: true>]>
user.dogs.with_spots
NoMethodError: undefined method 'with_spots' for #<MyEngine::Dog::ActiveRecord_Association_CollectionProxy:0x007fa4bf838e50>
```

Although this works

```
class User < MyEngine::User
  has_many :dogs
end
```

I would prefer not to redefine/define all of the associations in the main apps.

This type of problem is just going to keep occurring in different forms throughout all of my main applications. This made me think that there may be a way to redefine the associations.

Is there a way to evaluate the association on the subclass instead of the superclass much like the STI pattern to get Rails helpers to recognize different subclasses?

Meaning, I would like my main app User#dogs to return main app Dog instead of MyEngine::Dog.

```
# may not be the exact code, just off the top of my head

instance_eval do
  def model_name
    self.class.name
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Important Note** You can't query `user.dogs.with_spots`, even without inheritance. Your probably mean to get array of `Dog`s in `user.dogs.to_a`.

**Solution** The most general way to solve your problem is to use [Single Table Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Table_Inheritance).

Let's see how it works.

I will assume there are already tables `my_engine_users` and `my_engine_dogs` defined with all the required columns (as much as `MyEngine` module is concerned).

Classes `MyEngine::User` and `MyEngine::Dog` remain unchanged.

Classes `User` and `Dog` just extend respective engine-classes without any additional declarations about relations among them.

What we do, we tell Rails, that the two tables might be used by different classes (via extension). It's easily achievable by adding `type` column to the tables.

```
add_column :my_engine_users, :type, :string
```

and

```
 add_column :my_engine_dogs, :type, :string
```

Now you can do all the wonderful things with your users and dogs.

```
dimakura = User.create(username: 'dimakura')
dora = Dog.create(name: 'Dora', owner: dimakura)
fanta = Dog.create(name: 'Fanta', owner: dimakura)
dimakura.dogs.to_a # => array of Dogs, not MyEngine::Dogs
```

This magic is achieved by explicitly writing class name in `type` column.

```
p dimakura #=> #<User id: 1, username: "dimakura", type: "User">
p dora #=> #<Dog id: 1, owner_id: 1, name: "Dora", type: "Dog">
p fanta #=> #<Dog id: 2, owner_id: 1, name: "Fanta", type: "Dog">
```

Comment: I never put it together that I was really just using STI. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

`MyEngine::User.dogs` returns [proxied by an association instance] a set of `MyEngine::Dog` instances, that in general might have no `with_spots` scope.

If you are aware that all `MyEngine::Dog`s “respond” to `with_spots`, just move the scope definition to `MyEngine::Dog`. If that is not the case, calling this scope on `MyEngine::User.dogs` makes no sense.

**UPD** the example added might be solved:

```
class MyEngine::Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  scope :with_spots, -> { self.class.const_get(:SCOPE_PROC) }
end

class Dog < MyEngine::Dog
  DOGS_WITH_SPOTS_IDS = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
  SCOPE_PROC = -> { where(name: DOGS_WITH_SPOTS_IDS }
end
```

Comment: You are correct, however not all instances of MyEngine::Dog respond to with_spots. My real life situation is a bit more complex than this. I will change my example to better match it.

Comment: While that solution does work, I don't want the engine to know about spots at all.

Comment: Engine does not know about scope ⇒ engine relation does not know about scope. That simple.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to post a follow up:

While @dimakura is correct, it still did not work for what I was trying to do. This is because Rails does not allow chaining scopes for STI. In the end, I removed the STI and used the following:

```
user = User.first
user.dogs.merge(Dog.with_spots)
```